# ExpressJS - Robots.txt not found in Directory

Tags: .htaccess, express, routes, robots.txt

This might not be related to my apps code itself, but I have an issue where my `robots.txt` file receives a `404` error when I try to check to see if it is visible to crawlers in the root of my directory. I feel like a common test if a robots.txt file is visible to crawlers is to check if you can access it through a GET request.

Error: `Cannot GET /robots.txt`

Do I need to set up routing with a `GET` request for my robots.txt file to appear and crawled? Could this be a similar reason as to why my `.htaccess` file requests are not working?

Comment: Have you tried placing it in /public folder?

Comment: Yes, this didn't fix my issue